# Replacing int values by hexadecimal values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, hex

I have the following code:

```
self.mapping = {
    120: A,
    216: B,
    169: C
}
```

I would like a way of using hexadecimal representation of the bytes instead the decimal

One way to do this would be:

```
 self.mapping = {
        bytes.fromhex ('78'): A,
        bytes.fromhex ('D8'): B,
        bytes.fromhex ('A9'): C
 }
```

However, when I do this I receive a error message like this:

> Exception: Obj not found
>   on this line:
>       obj = self.mapping.get (test, None)
>               if obj is None:
>                   raise Exception ("Obj not found")

on the last line of this code sequence:

```
obj = self.mapping.get (byte, None)
        if obj is None:
            raise Exception ("Obj not found")
```

Plus, as far as I know, this does not work on old Python. So I would like a solution that works on 2.6 besides 3.2 and newer.
I read that bytestream could be the solution to deal with hexadecimal values, but I am unsure if it can be used with dictionaries and if can, how the syntax would be.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks, changed the code to use it.

Answer (score 2):

`bytes.fromhex` returns a `bytes` value (a sequence of bytes), not a byte directly. If you want to parse hex into an int, you can do that with `int`:

```
>>> int('78', 16)
120
```

and if they were literals in the first place, Python has hexadecimal int literals:

```
self.mapping = {
    0x78: A,
    0xD8: B,
    0xA9: C
}
```